# Adding style by setTimeout to dynamically added list element REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wan't to add style after some time after list element is rendered.

i Already tried something like this, but it's not working at all

```
   const errorList = Object.values(errors).map((el,i)=>{
        console.log(el)

        if(el === "required"){
            return <li  key={i} onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, i)}
                        style={{visibility: setTimeout(()=>{
                                return "hidden"
                            }, 500)}}

                        className="text-black-14px">This field is required</li>
        } else if(el === "non-error"){

            return <li  key={i} onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, i)}  style={margin} className="text-black-14px green">This field is OK</li>
        }
          else {
            return <li  key={i}  onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, i)} style={margin} className="text-black-14px">{el}</li>
        }
    })
```

Is there any way to add styling by setTimeOut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could e.g. have a separate state variable `showErrors` that you set to `true` when you set the errors, and then use a `setTimeout` for setting `showErrors` back to `false` after some time.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    errors: ["required", "non-error", "foo"],
    showErrors: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ showErrors: false });
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.values(this.state.errors).map((el, i) => {
          if (el === "required") {
            return (
              <li
                key={i}
                style={{
                  visibility: this.state.showErrors ? "visible" : "hidden"
                }}
                className="text-black-14px"
              >
                This field is required
              </li>
            );
          } else if (el === "non-error") {
            return (
              <li key={i} className="text-black-14px green">
                This field is OK
              </li>
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <li key={i} className="text-black-14px">
                {el}
              </li>
            );
          }
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to contain the information in your state, since your node will have to re-render itself after the timeout is over. The `setTimeout` should be in your `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to fire once the component is mounted :

```
componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ isHidden: true })
    }, 500)
}
```

And your original state with `isHidden` set to false :

```
state = {
    isHidden: false
}
```

The `style` variable will take the value out of the state if the field is required :

```
style={el === "required" ? { visibility: this.state.isHidden } : margin}
```

Also, the code you gave can be reduced to the following by using inline conditions :

```
const errorList = Object.values(errors).map((el, i) => {
    console.log(el)
    return <li 
        key={i} 
        onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, i)} 
        style={el === "required" ? { visibility: this.state.isHidden } : margin} 
        className={el === 'non-error' ? "text-black-14px green" : "text-black-14px"}>
        {{
            'required': 'This field is required',
            'non-error': 'This field is OK'
        }[el] || el}
    </li>
})
```